# gcc: how to only trace specific functions calls

Tags: c, gcc

Options `-pg`, `-mfentry` and `-finstrument-functions` affects all functions in a `.c` file,
How can I insert trace call only into specific functions, but not all?

I checked [gcc function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) but it seems there's no counterparts to `-pg`, `-mfentry` and `-finstrument-functions` that can be used to decorate only to specific functions.

`no_instrument_function` excludes functions but what I want is the opposite, i.e., to includes functions.

Comment: You might customize GCC with your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension to do that.

Answer (score 0):

With `-finstrument-functions`, you could filter the function address in __cyg_profile_func_enter and __cyg_profile_func_exit to go on with only the functions you want to trace.

To be more friendly and filter by function names instead of their addresses, you could build a hash table from the data of the symbol table.